# Child div needs to overlap on its parent such that it gets parent's background color

Tags: css

I have the below structure:

```
<li style="border-left-color: green">
  <div class="some icon">
   <div class="another icon">
  </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

I need to allow the div that has "some icon" overlap the left border of my li element such that the icon appears within the green color bar.

Can the child div overlap on it's parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Something like the following should work, however, your class names should not contain spaces:

```
li {
    position: relative;
    height: // whatever your desired height is
    border-left: 20px solid green;
}

.some_icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:-20px; // this should be the same as, or similar to, the li border width
}
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/verism/z2ormyxo/).